# Android Viewholder onclicklistener multiple click

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a issue on the viewholder onclicklistener.
When I press the image, it will launch another activity.
If I press on the image a lot of times, it will launch multiple activities.

How can I let the onclicklistener to only launch one activity?

```
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.epi_list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.month_year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.month_year);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

            holder.status = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.ecg_view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ecg_view);
            //holder.ecg_view = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ecg_view);
            holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ecg_checkbox_select);


           convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


         holder.date.setText(mDate[position].toString().substring(8));
            holder.month_year.setText(mDate[position].toString().substring(0, 7));
            holder.time.setText(mTime[position].toString());


            if(mUpdate[position].toString().equals("1")){
                //holder.status.setText("Sent");
                holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sent_icon);
            }else if(mUpdate[position].toString().equals("0")){
                //holder.status.setText("Pending");
                holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pending_icon);
            }


            holder.ecg_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        getParsedMyXML(position, mFiles.get(position), true);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block                  
                    }

                    // Launch another activity
                    startDrawing(mData, mDate[position] + " " + mTime[position]);
                }
            });


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Are you making an asyn call in getParsedMyXML ?

Comment: No async call in getParsedMyXML

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick method`, try this:

```
   if(firstClick == true) {
     firstClick = false;
     // Launch another activity
     startDrawing(mData, mDate[position] + " " + mTime[position]);
   }
```

Declare `firstClick` as a global boolean variable which is initially set to `true`.  The other activity can then modify the `firstClick` value back to `true` when appropriate.

Comment: I have try this method it does not work. It will still trigger multiple "onclick event" when there are multiple clicks on the view holder image